# If I make a transferred DNS zone a standard primary, does that affect anything other than making it static?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-2000

I do not want to break anything, but if I have a currently transferred zone, and I want to make it static, do I not just make it a Standard Primary?  I have several zones, but this is not one that is in my domain/forest.  I do not want to break the existing zones.

I am having difficulty with the one what is being transferred, and since the information doesn't change much, I wanted to make it static.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have administrative access to the server holding the Primary zone and don't have administrative access to that Primary zone, then nothing you do to the Secondary zone can have any affect on the Primary zone.

You would need to administratively access the server holding the Primary zone and make changes to that Primary zone in order to affect the Primary zone.

Comment: I am on the server.  I am an administrator.  I have my main zone that I put in there for my forest.  I have an outside forest that I was transferring because I need to resolve some of their names.  But, they change it very little, and I wanted to make their there transfer static with Standard Primary (not AD.)

Comment: You're not on the server that holds the Primary zone, you're on your server that holds the Secondary zone, right? If so, then nothing you can do to the Secondary zone or server will have any affect on the Primary zone or server. Now that you've given a little more info on the scenario, why don't you just set up a conditional forwarder on your server for the external zone?